# Cassandra hosting

Tags: web-hosting, cloud-hosting

What is needed to host website which uses Cassandra?

Are there any available options on market right now?

What other NoSQL hosting plans do you recommend?

Comment: Get VPS and install whatever NoSQL software you want -- NoSQL are quite specific compared to widely used Relational DBMS (MySQL etc) that I doubt you will find any decent (first of all from cost perspective) Shared Hosting plan with NoSQL options.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any existing DaaS (Database as a Service) company that provides support for Cassandra. There's also a [similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635223/what-are-the-cheap-hosting-solutions-for-cassandra), and the answer is always the same: setup a VPS and install Cassandra on your server.

Conversely, there are several alternatives for other NoSQL and/or Document Oriented Databases such as CouchDB, MongoDB and Redis.

If you want to use MongoDB, [MongoLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635223/what-are-the-cheap-hosting-solutions-for-cassandra) and [MongoHQ](http://mongohq.com) provides several hosting plans. For CouchDB, [Cloudant](https://cloudant.com/) is by far the most known provider.